# Scala Play: Where does Heroku store the assets i.e. everything under public?

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm deploying a Play 2.7.x Application in Heroku and my search capability based on Lucene is crashing because of not finding the `public` folder containing the documents to index. I then logged into the Heroku deployment and I see there are only binaries, I searched on the root i.e. on top of `../app` but no luck finding my public assets.

**UPDATE** I'm deploying using Heroku CLI and the SBT plugin `sbt stage deployHeroku`

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you deploy? `git push` or `sbt deployHeroku`?

Comment: is the `public` dir in your local Git repo?

Comment: @codefinger yes it’s!